# Make flex item be the width of its text

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to have a layout with two columns, where the left column is some kind of sidebar.

Now I want to use some text in the sidebar that shouldn't wrap.

When I do so it causes some kind of overflow and then using `overflow:hidden` hides a good part of the text.

How can I modify the left column to use the width of the unwrapped text and the right column to use the remaining space without dropping `overflow:hidden`?

```css
#container {
    display: flex;
}
#sidebar {
    border: 1px solid red;
    flex 1 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#sidebar .column {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#sidebar .column span {
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 2px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    display: inline-block;
}
#content {
    border: 1px solid black;
    flex: 1 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="sidebar">
        <div class="column">
            <span>Howdy Cowboy, some text is missing here</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        Some funny content
    </div>
</div>
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/8jjzpm7b/1/)

Comment: Do you mean like this https://jsfiddle.net/8jjzpm7b/4/ ?

Comment: yes.. need to get my head wrapped around this

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> How can I modify the left column to use the width of the unwrapped text and the right column to use the remaining space without dropping `overflow:hidden`?

Tell the left column to be only as wide as its content.

So instead of this:

```
#sidebar {
  flex: 1 auto;            /* 1 */
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Use this:

```
#sidebar {
  flex: 0 1 auto;        /* 1 */
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

And tell the right column to consume any remaining space.

Instead of this:

```
#content {
  flex: 1 100%;         /* 2 */
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Use this:

```
#content {
  flex: 1;              /* 2 */
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

[**revised fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/8jjzpm7b/5/)

Notes:

1. `flex: 1 auto` is shorthand for `flex-grow: 1` (defined), `flex-shrink: 1` (by default) and `flex-basis: auto` (defined). Switch to `flex-grow: 0` since you don't want the box to expand beyond the content.

   Incidentally, `flex-grow: 0`, `flex-shrink: 1` and `flex-basis: auto` are all [default values](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-components). Hence, you can omit the `flex` rule and get the same result.

   *Note that your code won't work in any case because you have a syntax error (a missing `:`)*.
2. `flex-basis: 100%` will force the item to expand as much as it can across the width of the container, even intruding into the sidebar space if it can. Just use `flex: 1` (same as `flex-grow: 1`, `flex-shrink: 1`, `flex-basis: 0`), which tells the item to consume only *free* space.