# Making flexbox shrink to size before wrapping

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make a responsive page that has the following behavior:

I need two `<a>` tags, one next to the other. These tags have an icon in a `<i>` tag and a `<span>` tag with some text in it.

As the viewport reduces in width, I want the icon to keep the same size but I want the text to wrap as much as possible before pushing the second `<a>` to the next line. This image shows in sequence what I want to happen:

[image]

[This CodePen](http://codepen.io/beheks/pen/ObLQzV) is as close as I got. The functionality I want is there, but I had to set `flex-basis: 100px` and `flex-grow: 1` in `.outer-item` to make it work, which has the undesirable effect of making both items the same width and spreading them in the available space.

```css
.outer-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.outer-item {
  flex: 1 0 100px;
}

.inner-container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.inner-img {
  flex: 0 0 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
}

.inner-label {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-wrapper">
  <a class="outer-item">
    <div class="inner-container">
      <i class="inner-img">img</i>
      <span class="inner-label">label label label label</span>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="outer-item">
    <div class="inner-container">
      <i class="inner-img">img</i>
      <span class="inner-label">label label label label label label label </span>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Is there a way to make it work? Is flexbox even the way to go or should I use something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The functionality I want is there, but I had to set `flex-basis: 100px` and `flex-grow: 1` in `.outer-item` to make it work, which has the undesirable effect of making both items the same width and spreading them in the available space.

You have `outer-wrapper` set to `display: flex`, which acts like a block-level container (i.e., it will occupy all available space on the line).

Instead, use `display: inline-flex`, which will consume only enough width to accommodate the content.

[**revised codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bBbver)

Comment: Thanks @Michael_B but I wanted flexbox to set each anchor's width to only wrap their children, instead of both having the same width. I believe this is happening because of `.outer-item{ flex: 1 0 100px }`, which sets `flex-grow: 1` making both anchors have the same weight when `.outer-wrapper` decides its children widths. I was looking for a way to get rid of that.

Comment: Maybe my answer here will help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40388954/3597276

Comment: Your answer did help, but I'm not quite there yet. In [this CodePen](http://codepen.io/beheks/pen/ZBzwEB?editors=1100) I managed to get rid of the extra spacing, but I couldn't get the wrapping to work. If I set `flex-wrap: wrap` in `.outer-wrapper`, flexbox panics and wraps before shrinking. Any thoughts?

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit tricky. You may want to consider a media query that enables `wrap` only on narrow screens ([**codepen demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aBoeLm?editors=1100)).

Comment: Felipe, you may find some more guidance in this post: [*Make flex items wrap in nested flex containers before containers themselves wrap in main container*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32661535/3597276). Good luck!